# Laravel 5.4 Auth Register change table

Tags: laravel-5.4

i changed the default table login table by adding

```php
    protected $table = 'client_table';

```

But when trying to use the default laravel Auth registration form it insists to use the table users

Comment: Were you able to resolve this issue?

Answer (score 3):

You should only have to make the change that you made, ie:

```
protected $table = 'different_table';
```

If using the registration functionality then you will also need to change your RegisterController's validator() function:

```
'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:users',
```

Should become:

```
'email' => 'required|string|email|max:255|unique:different_table',
```

Answer (score 0):

Go to

> config/auth.php

You should modify the following code :

```
/*
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
| User Providers
|--------------------------------------------------------------------------
|
| All authentication drivers have a user provider. This defines how the
| users are actually retrieved out of your database or other storage
| mechanisms used by this application to persist your user's data.
|
| If you have multiple user tables or models you may configure multiple
| sources which represent each model / table. These sources may then
| be assigned to any extra authentication guards you have defined.
|
| Supported: "database", "eloquent"
|
*/

'providers' => [
    'users' => [
        'driver' => 'eloquent',
        'model' => App\User::class,
    ],

    // 'users' => [
    //     'driver' => 'database',
    //     'table' => 'users',
    // ],
],
```

You'll maybe also need to modify the validator method in the RegisterController.

Comment: Which part of `config/auth.php` should be changed? `'table' => 'users'`? but that configuration is for database driver only. So, if i use eloquent cant change default user table? i tried to add `$table = "myuser"` to user model, but the register action insist try to find default users table. sorry for bad english :D

Answer (score 0):

during registration need to make small change in **protected function validator**

Change 'unique:users' to 'unique:user' in line as below
'email' => ['required', 'string', 'email', 'max:255', 'unique:user'],